# After opening iTerm2, the session closes right away

Tags: iterm2

My iTerm2 closes right away when I click on the icon. I have seen that this is a known issue with iTerm2, but most of the solutions involve editing preferences through the menu. However, I can not access the menu items. Also, I can not resize the window to get the alert to move out of the way so now I can't read the information displayed. Finally, I don't see any error logs. Any ideas?

iTerm2 build 3.3.12 running on Mojave 10.14.6
[image]

Comment: You might get help sooner at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).